# Python how to search a specific string in file

Tags: python, file

Hello guys i have the follow file:

```
Name: xxx
Surname: xx
```

Another personal data in the same format (Age: 20, etc...)

After this data i have this:

```
URL picture 1:  data:image/png;base64 and etc... (encoded image)
URL picture 2:  data:image/png;base64 not the same code of picture1
```

I have to do two different things if I read the `picture 1` or `picture 2`, so when I read URL `picture 1` do a thing if it read URL `picture 2` another thing.

I have the python script but not working, don't separate them.

```
with open(pathUserFile,'a+') as f:
f.seek(0)
for line in f:
    if line.find('URL foto 1:') != -1:
        url_pic = line[line.find(',') + 1:]
        url_pic = url_pic.strip()
        decoded_pic = base64.b64decode(url_pic)
        name_of_file = createUserDirectory(pathUserFile, decoded_pic, False)
        info = DeepFace.analyze(name_of_file, ['emotion'])
        domEmot1 = str(info['dominant_emotion'])
        print(domEmot1)
    if line.find('URL foto 2:') != -1:
        print('foto 2')
```

output:

```
Actions to do:  ['emotion']
'neutral'
foto 2
Actions to do:  ['emotion']
'fear'
foto 2
```

why he does for two times the same things? only one has got the analyze

Comment: post some examples and desired output

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi the problem is that do the same thing two times, but when it reads the url picture 2 it shouldn't call the analyze method

Comment: first use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed - it is called "print debuging" You could check what you get in `line` - `print(line)` and `print( line.find('URL foto 1:'), line.find('URL foto 2:') ). Maybe you have `foto 2` two times. OR you don't have `foto 1` but `picture 1`

Comment: how many URLS do you have in file ? maybe you have `foto 1`, `foto 2` and later you have another `foto 1`, `foto 2` - so this gives you four results - and it analyze two times because you have two `foto 2`. Better check what you have in file - and check also `print(line)`